# Why is the diameter of a circumcircle of a triangle related to the law of sines?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Please refer to the following image for clarity.

In this diagram I must find AC ( which is$\sqrt21$) in order to find the radius of the circle. I know that the radius can be found by dividing the diameter by $2$, and I know that the diameter is equal to AC/sin(60). My question is, why is this true? Why is the diameter equal to this?

[image]

Comment: In first line is question saying that AC is $\sqrt{7}$ or that must first find AC then multiply that by $\sqrt{7}$? Also why should diameter be AC/$\sin 60$ ?

Comment: The question says find AC. AC=sqrt(7) according to my work. The answer sheet says that's how you find the radius and also this website https://www.mathopenref.com/trianglecircumcircle.html

Comment: Is your question why $\frac{AC}{\sin 60}= diameter$? If this is the question, it is due to law of sines. Search for it.

Comment: @CletoPereira I know it is related to law of sines... My question is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Simple construction. AE is the diameter through circum-center $O$. $\angle ACE= 90^{\circ},$ subtended in semi-circle $ADCE$. Subtended angles on$B$ side of $AC$ are always the same in magnitude.

So, the hypotenuse or diameter

$$ AE =\frac{AC}{\sin 60^{\circ}}$$

Repeat this thrice, once each for three of the vertices A,B or C and you have already derived the Law of Sines:

$$ \frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}= AE $$

Answer (score 2):

If $AB$ and $BC$ are $5$ and $4$, as indicated, then 
$$
AC^2=AB^2+BC^2-2|AB||BC|\cos 60=25+16-40\frac12=21
$$ 
by the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). Hence $|AC|=\sqrt{21}$, not $\sqrt{7}$. The [circumdiameter](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Circumradius) is the product of all sides divided by twice the area, and the area is half the product of two adjacent sides times the sine of the angle between them:
$$
D=\frac{abc}{2A}=\frac{abc}{2\left(\frac12 ab\sin\angle(a,b)\right)}
=\frac{c}{\sin\angle(a,b)}.
$$
So what's left is the opposite side divided by twice the sine of the angle, i.e. $AC/\sin(60)$.

This explains why all the ratios in the law of sines are equal, they are [all equal to the circumdiameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Relation_to_the_circumcircle). Basically, this is because one can create a new right triangle, where the diameter is opposite the right angle, and one other side is a side of the original triangle with the same opposite angle. This is based on the Inscribed Angle theorem, see the linked Wikipedia proof.

Answer (score 2):

Add the center of the circumcircle at $O$ and drop the perpendicular onto $\overline{AC}$ from $O$ at $D$.

[image]

The [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) says that $\angle AOC$ is twice $\angle ABC$, so that $\angle AOD=\angle COD=\angle ABC$. Therefore,
$$
\overline{AC}=2r\sin(B)
$$

Answer (score 1):

If your question is why $\frac{AD}{\sin 60}= 2R$ check the vídeo 
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95Slthp8o_4)

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABC$ a triangle with acute angle $\gamma$, let $M$ be the center of the circumcircle and $r$ be its radius.  By moving $C$ on the arc over $AB$ the angle $\gamma$ doesn't change; move it to the intersection $C'$ of $AM$ and the circle.  From Thales the triangle $ABC'$ is right-angled with a right angle at $B$.  Hence $\sin(\gamma)=AB/2r$.